# Frenet Serret Deduction

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I want to demonstrate that:
$ \frac{d\hat{B}}{ds} = -\tau \hat{N}(s) $

knowing that:

$ \frac{d\hat{T}}{ds} = \kappa \hat{N}(s) $ and $\tau = - \frac{d\hat{B}}{ds}.\hat{N}(s)$

Comment: You should note also that $\hat B$ is defined by
$$
\hat B = \hat T \times \hat N
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating $B = T \times N$, $$\dfrac{dB}{ds} = \dfrac{dT}{ds} \times N + T \times \dfrac{dN}{ds}$$  But the first term is $0$, thus $$\dfrac{dB}{ds} =  T \times \dfrac{dN}{ds} \perp T$$ 
Differentiating $B \cdot B = 1$, we find $$\dfrac{dB}{ds} \perp B$$
Thus $\dfrac{dB}{ds}$ must be a multiple of $N$, and knowing $\dfrac{dB}{ds} \cdot N$ does the rest.